# EditText not work

Tags: android

This is my code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        markerlocationtext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);

        final LocationManager manager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(googleServicesAvailabile()){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            iniMap();
        }

        if(!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
        markerlocationtext.setText("Lat : "); //i put any word for test but not work
}
```

and I got this error when run my application

> 11-27 12:38:03.628 16781-16781/com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                  Process: com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi, PID: 16781
>                                                                                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi/com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                      at
>   com.project.ytubasi.speedtaxi.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:65)
>                                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5287)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                                                                                      at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1223) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:855) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671) 
>                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is ur question ?

Comment: plese add more detail about what is the problem and what you need .

Comment: In the code you comment , one issue i noted is u not should call the view before the setContentView is set. So you move the textview initialization to the bottom of the  setContentView

Comment: is that you mean `TextView`? I see no `EditText` in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the resource xml file which contains your textView..

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourXmlFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must call `setContentView` method before any view binding using `findViewById`
so you must move below the code line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); <-------

        markerlocationtext=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);

        final LocationManager manager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(googleServicesAvailabile()){
            iniMap();
        }

        if(!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();
        }
        markerlocationtext.setText("Lat : "); //i put any word for test but not work
}
```